# Push data into a certain position in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I push some data into a certain place in an array?

I am trying the code below:

```
Keys[1].push({ Keys: "Test" });
```

But it doesn't seem to work as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you are looking for is `splice`

```
arrayObject.splice(index,0,{Keys:"Test"});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice